# Как проверить, есть ли один из элементов одного списка, в элементе другого списка?

Tags: python, list

Есть 2 списка:

```py
a = ["привет", "заказ", "123", "100", "шт", "345", "500бухт", "и", "678", "700м"]

b = ["шт", "бухт", "м"]
```

Нужно проверить, содержит ли элемент первого списка элемент из второго списка. Но если элемент из первого списка равен элементу из второго списка, то мы не добавляем его в новый список. В итоге нужно получить список:

```
['500бухт', '700м']
```

Делать это через 2 цикла или есть проще выход?

Answer (score 3):

Это смотря что называть циклом. Вот вместо двух вложенных `for` два `filter` с `lambda`, но по сути то это всё-равно цикл в цикле сложностью `O(n^2)`:

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: any(filter(lambda y: y in x and x != y, b)), a)))
```

Вывод:

```
['500бухт', '700м']
```

P.S. Кстати, MaxU прав - мало ли где внутри слова может встретиться буква "м". Лучше, наверное, и правда использовать регулярки, ну или хотя бы проверять не через `in`, а через `endswith`, если строка из `b` должна быть в конце строки, и что до того идёт число тоже можно проверить без регулярок через `isdigit`:

```
print(list(
    filter(lambda x: any(
        filter(lambda y: x.endswith(y) and
                      x[:-len(y)].isdigit() and
                      x != y,
               b)
        ), a)
    ))
```

Answer (score 3):

По-моему данную задачу нужно решать используя регулярные выражения. Наверняка у вас в реальном списке будут слова, в которых встречается буква "м" и которые не имеют никакого отношения к метрам.

```
import re

a = ["привет", "трям!", "заказ", "123", "100", "шт", "345", "500бухт", "и", "678", "700м"]
b = ["шт", "бухт", "м"]

pat = r"\d+\s*(?:{})".format("|".join(b))
res = [x for x in a if re.search(pat, x)]
```

результат:

```
In [522]: res
Out[522]: ['500бухт', '700м']
```

Answer (score 2):

Да, делать через 2 цикла. Если хотите сократить код, то можете воспользоваться [списковым включением](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

***Пример:***

```py
a = ['привет', 'заказ', '123', '100', 'шт', '345', '500бухт', 'и', '678', '700м']
b = ['шт', 'бухт', 'м']

d = [x for y in b for x in a if y in x and x != y]
print(d)
```

***stdout:***

```py
['500бухт', '700м']
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну при желании можно одним циклом обойтись, правда не уверен, что так будет лучше:

```
a = ['привет', 'заказ', '123', '100', 'шт', '345', '500бухт', 'и', '678', '700м']
b = ['шт', 'бухт', 'м']

c = [*filter(lambda x: any(i in x for i in b if i!=x), a)]  # ['500бухт', '700м']
```

Answer (score 2):

совсем без циклов получилось собрать такую неуклюжую, но рабочую конструкцию:

```
import pandas as pd

arr = pd.Series(a)
expr = '|'.join(b)
c = arr[arr.str.contains(expr,regex=True)&~arr.str.fullmatch(expr)].to_list()

# ['500бухт', '700м']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List1 = ['python', 'JS', 'c#', 'go', 'c', 'c++']
List2 = ['c#', 'Java', 'python']

check = any(item in List1 for item in List2)

if check:
    print("The list1 contains some elements of the list2")
else:
    print("No, List1 doesn't have any elements of the List2.")
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В вопросе указано, что нужно найти сами элементы, а не просто проверить их наличие.

Comment: К тому же, будет реагировать на строку "шт" без числа. В общем, вы какую-то другую задачу тут решаете.

Comment: insolor, а Вы хотели, чтобы я всё за него набил? Я идею дал и хорошую. Мне помогло...

Comment: Это не идея, это решение другой задачи. Если вам помогло, значит у вас другая задача была.